# how to verify jwt token in nodejs / never expire?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I implemented `JWT` token in node js.I am able to generate `jwt` token.Now I want to check when it will **expire or invalid** .
I check the documentation it says after `120ms` it will expire .but I my token is not expire .it always decode the token why ?

I generate the token like this
'

```
app.get("/saveData", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = await userService.create({
      userId: "abcp",
      password: "hello",
      appsAccess: ["yes", "test"]
    });

    res.send(token);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

**and verify the token like this**

```
app.get("/verify-token", async (req, res) => {
  let tokenStatus = await userService.verifyAccessToken(
    "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7InVzZXJJZCI6ImFiY3AiLCJhcHBzQWNjZXNzIjpbInllcyIsInRlc3QiXSwiX2lkIjoiNWQ3Yzk4MTYzZmQ1NGIwOGUwMjYzNjg0IiwiX192IjowfSwiaWF0IjoxNTY4NDQ2NDg2LCJpc3MiOiJqamoiLCJzdWIiOiJhYmNwIn0.1fqzYJ1p9jSIiNjbA7MwEsU4EsMmmpxF34TU1ZjonSA"
  );
  res.send(tokenStatus);
});
```

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-tree-hd0fo

```
verifyAccessToken(token) {
    return jwt.verify(token, "jhjhhj");
  }
```

I want if i generate the token it will expire after `10min` or `30min`..etc

Comment: Heres a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jsonwebtoken-test-vfe8q, which you can pick apart, read through it you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expiresIn` option to do this. Example based on your code:

```
const token = jwt.sign(payload, "jhjhhj", {
  algorithm: "HS256",
  issuer: "jjj",
  subject: `${user.userId}`,
  expiresIn: "10m"
});
```

Comment: but it always gives a token back...!! i added this for `1min`